# Assigning a data.table slice in R

Tags: r, data.table

In order to read a data.table slice, I can use the following syntax:

```
foo = DT[, 5:10, with=F]
```

but now I want to do:

```
foo = foo + 1
DT[, 5:10, with=F] = foo
```

This doesn't work; referring to the columns by names also doesn't seem to work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: It's all in the help file ``help(`:=`)``: `DT[, (5:10) := foo]`. Parens not required because the sequence operator `:` already makes the left-hand side a call.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  I get errors like:
flatData[, (4:7) := disc]
Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(flatData, , `:=`((4:7), disc)) :
  4 column matrix RHS of := will be treated as one vector

Comment: @rimorob please present a complete example in your post

Comment: I have figured out the answer, putting together @BlueMagister's answer and some info inside help(":=").  It turns out that RHS (in my examples, 'foo' and 'disc') has to be a data frame so that it can be treated as a list!  It all makes sense.  Eventually.  With effort and a lot of therapy.

Comment: @rimorob Then you can answer your own question, and mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little more subtle. This is how I read your question and how you're trying to do it at the moment ...

Your first line creates a new `data.table` object with the 6-column subset of columns :

```
foo = DT[, 5:10, with=F]
```

I'm immediately thinking of the memory implications.  If each column is 1GB,  that's a 6GB new object you just allocated.

then you +1 to everything in that 6GB :

```
foo = foo + 1   # or something like that, that works
```

That's a copy of that 6GB to another new 6GB.

Then you copy the 6GB `foo` back into where it was in `DT` in the first place :

```
DT[, 5:10, with=F] = foo    # or something like that, that works
```

That's really memory inefficient. It's a base R way of doing things.

In `data.table` you can loop, and you can `set`. I would just do it in an easy to read and easy to understand loop.

```
for (col in 5:10)
    set(DT, j=col, value=DT[[col]]+1)
```

This changes each column by reference one-by-one. `DT[[col]]` doesn't copy the column contents (that's nothing special in `data.table`, that's base R that doesn't copy).  But the `+1` does create a new vector.  However, that new vector is then *plonked* directly into the column pointer slot, so it's as efficient as it can be given that `+1` returns a new object.

Comment: This is better than my solution, mainly due to the memory management considerations!  R is horrible in this regard, and data.table seems to be a giant step forward!